# How to send SOLR DateTime range request through HTTP?

Tags: http, solr

I want to be able to query a date-time range on my solr index. Through the UI, I can type the search query in like so:

```
dateUTC:[2012-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2013-01-01T00:00:00Z]
```

Which then generates a URL in the browser like so:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?q=dateUTC%3A%5B2012-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z+TO+2013-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%5D&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

Which then show some results in XML formatting in my browser. (Note, I'm using a server with version 2.2 of SOLR). My goal is to eventually write a script to pull this data, but I cannot seem to be able to make this request through a script.

My test.bat file looks something like:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?q=dateUTC%3A%5B2012-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z+TO+2013-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%5D&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on" > test.xml
```

However, when I look at test.xml, the xml results are empty. I suspect it has to do with some characters not getting interpreted correctly because the simpler query "foobar" works fine and generates the xml file I'm looking for:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?q=foobar&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on > testSuccess.xml
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try replacing foobar in your last example with the query from your first example, and the wrapping the URL in double quotes (since it now contains spaces)? This way you let curl take care of URL-encoding.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, the issue was very straightforward. %'s are special characters on command prompt, so you have to escape those correctly too (just do %% instead of %). By adding an extra % symbol everywhere, the request now worked!

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?q=dateUTC%%3A%%5B2012-01-01T00%%3A00%%3A00Z+TO+2013-01-01T00%%3A00%%3A00Z%%5D&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on" > test.xml
```